# react native redux props not getting updated when the screen render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native

i am not adding reducers and actions here because thats working fine , im getting the `banner objects` from the server . 
Here the problem is when i do `console.log(this.props.banner_list)` in the render. it seems  that render method getting called two times and for the first time `this.props.banner_list` is undefined and its throwing error when i try to show the objects inside the view. And second time when it renders its showing the `this.props.banner_list` correctly in the `console` . i didnt understand whats happening here. somebody please help me

```
class App extends Component<Props> {

    componentDidMount(){
       this.props.getBanners()
    }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)// here iam logging the props

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       // its throwing error so i comment it , i can see the render 
       // getting called two times. first time its undefined .
        {banner_list.banners.banners.map(obj=>{
          return(
            <Text>{obj.title}</Text>
          )
        })}  

      </View>
    );
  }


function mapStateToProps(state){
      return {
        banners_list:state.banners
      }   
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators({getBanners}, dispatch)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that when the `App` component renders for the first time, your redux store state `banners` is probably undefined. After the component mounts, calling `this.props.getBanners` will basically trigger an update to the redux store, which will in turn dispatch new props to the App component.

When the component receives new props, it will re-render based on the props received from the redux store.

So, while trying to access `banners_list.banners.banners.map`, an error will be returned on the first render because `banners_list` is empty. To mitigate this, you'll need to add a check in your render method like this...

```
render() {
  const { banners_list } = this.props;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      { 
        banners_list &&
          banners_list.banners.banners.map(obj=> (<Text>{obj.title}</Text>))
      }  
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Re **"it seems that render method getting called two times"**: Correct, it gets called twice. When your component gets mounted, `render()` is called. This triggers `componentDidMount()` to get called. When `componentDidMount()` gets called, it calls `this.props.getBanners()` as in your code. This triggers a re-render, which calls `render()` for the second time.

Re **"for the first time this.props.banner_list is undefined"** Correct. As mentioned above, the first render occurs BEFORE `componentDidMount()` is called, and therefore before `this.props.getBanners()` is called. At the point, `this.props` exists so an error is not thrown, but it does not yet contain a `banners` field, so it simply returns `undefined`.

Re **"its throwing error when i try to show the objects inside the view"** This occurs because if you try to render an undefined object inside a view, it throws an error. During this initial render, `this.props.banners` is undefined, hence the error.

The solution is to CONDITIONALLY RENDER the view. If you do `<View>{a && b}</View>`, if `a` is false then Javascript automatically renders this as `<View>null</View>` without bothering to check what `b` is. Thus, re-write your code as follows:

```
class App extends Component<Props> {

    componentDidMount(){
       this.props.getBanners()
    }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)// here iam logging the props

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       // its throwing error so i comment it , i can see the render 
       // getting called two times. first time its undefined .
        {banner_list.banners && banner_list.banners.banners.map(obj=>{
          return(
            <Text>{obj.title}</Text>
          )
        })}  

      </View>
    );
  }


function mapStateToProps(state){
      return {
        banners_list:state.banners
      }   
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators({getBanners}, dispatch)
    }
```

All I've added there ^^ is `banner_list.banners &&` before `banner_list.banners.banners.map` etc

Answer (score 1):

```
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)// here iam logging the props

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       // its throwing error so i comment it , i can see the render 
       // getting called two times. first time its undefined .
        {banner_list.banner && banner_list.banners.banners.map(obj=>{
          return(
            <Text>{obj.title}</Text>
          )
        })}  

      </View>
    );
  }
```

You could change that line of code. maybe what is happening is at the start of your state I imagine your redux state at first something like this

```
{
    banners:{}
}
```

and after

```
{
    banners:{
        banners:{
            banners:[
            {title:'Hello world'}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever you are trying to get a property that is undefined it will return an error so at first, you could ask for that property.